# How to set horizon to use less cpu usage in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, supervisord, laravel-horizon

I am using laravel horizon to monitor my queues. I have only two queue for which I am using redis and supervisor on my instance. It was not working when my ec2 instance was `micro` or `nano` i had to use `small` instance after that I decrease the number of process from 5 to 1. and now it is working on nano instance. but as there is only two jobs for background process I think it should also work on micro instance.
Please have a look at my horizon.php and supervisor conf file and let me know if I can make any more

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Horizon Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the subdomain where Horizon will be accessible from. If this
    | setting is null, Horizon will reside under the same domain as the
    | application. Otherwise, this value will serve as the subdomain.
    |
    */

    'domain' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Horizon Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the URI path where Horizon will be accessible from. Feel free
    | to change this path to anything you like. Note that the URI will not
    | affect the paths of its internal API that aren't exposed to users.
    |
    */

    'path' => 'horizon',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Horizon Redis Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the name of the Redis connection where Horizon will store the
    | meta information required for it to function. It includes the list
    | of supervisors, failed jobs, job metrics, and other information.
    |
    */

    'use' => 'default',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Horizon Redis Prefix
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This prefix will be used when storing all Horizon data in Redis. You
    | may modify the prefix when you are running multiple installations
    | of Horizon on the same server so that they don't have problems.
    |
    */

    'prefix' => env('HORIZON_PREFIX', 'horizon:'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Horizon Route Middleware
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These middleware will get attached onto each Horizon route, giving you
    | the chance to add your own middleware to this list or change any of
    | the existing middleware. Or, you can simply stick with this list.
    |
    */

    'middleware' => ['web','auth'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Queue Wait Time Thresholds
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to configure when the LongWaitDetected event
    | will be fired. Every connection / queue combination may have its
    | own, unique threshold (in seconds) before this event is fired.
    |
    */

    'waits' => [
        'redis:default' => 60,
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Job Trimming Times
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you can configure for how long (in minutes) you desire Horizon to
    | persist the recent and failed jobs. Typically, recent jobs are kept
    | for one hour while all failed jobs are stored for an entire week.
    |
    */

    'trim' => [
        'recent' => 60,
        'completed' => 60,
        'recent_failed' => 10080,
        'failed' => 10080,
        'monitored' => 10080,
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Fast Termination
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When this option is enabled, Horizon's "terminate" command will not
    | wait on all of the workers to terminate unless the --wait option
    | is provided. Fast termination can shorten deployment delay by
    | allowing a new instance of Horizon to start while the last
    | instance will continue to terminate each of its workers.
    |
    */

    'fast_termination' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Memory Limit (MB)
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value describes the maximum amount of memory the Horizon worker
    | may consume before it is terminated and restarted. You should set
    | this value according to the resources available to your server.
    |
    */

    'memory_limit' => 64,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Queue Worker Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the queue worker settings used by your application
    | in all environments. These supervisors and settings handle all your
    | queued jobs and will be provisioned by Horizon during deployment.
    |
    */

    'environments' => [
        'production' => [
            'supervisor-1' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['default'],
                'balance' => 'auto',
                'processes' => 1,
                'tries' => 2,
            ],
           
        ],

        'local' => [
            'supervisor-1' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['default'],
                'balance' => 'auto',
                'processes' => 1,
                'tries' => 2,
            ],
           
        ],
    ],
];
```

supervisor conf

```
[program:queue-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/coldxcoldxlogistics/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/coldxcoldxlogistics/worker.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I set `memory_limit` to `10mb` and reduced process from 5 to 1. now system is working fine on `micro` instance

Answer (score 0):

Your supervisor.conf numprocs=8 will start 8 horizon master processes. Each Horizon master process would then start 1 process. That’s 8 process.

That’s what consuming the cpu cycles and might not be the desired results. You can solve it by removing the numprocs from supervisor.conf